# Replacing the compiler in Visual C++ 6

Tags: visual-c++

Can I use Microsoft Development Studio (a.k.a. Visual C++ 6), but replacing its awful compiler with that of Visual C++ 2005 or, even better, GCC? If so, how?

Comment: If you prefer Visual C++ 2005, why not just use that instead?

Comment: Well, because I'm using a virtual machine and VS2005 is slow like a cow. I don't want to stop doing other stuff just to open an IDE.

Comment: If you're in a memory constrained envrionment, you may be better off using a more lightweight editor (something like Vim or Notepad++) and the command line VS build tools. Then you can use a 2005 project and only open the IDE when you need to.

Comment: Can I edit my resource files using anything other than VC++'s resource editor?

Comment: Resource files (.rc files) are just text files.  You can edit them with any text editor.  The GUI editor is just some special sauce that VS gives you, but I find it cumbersome and always just hand code the resource files.

Comment: There is still a huge difference between using even the best of editors, and a full IDE. Many will object me for saying this, but vim/emacs ... are still just editors; they can replace IDE in some ways, but that't all just patchwork. And, to Eduardo ... I agree; although newer versions sure look nice/have even some nice options, I could never give up the simplicity and responsiveness of the old VStudios.

Comment: RC files are a pig to hand-edit in my experience, compared to XML/HTML type files (though I'm sure practice helps). Just because it's a text file doesn't mean it's designed for hand-editing...

Comment: I have hand-edited both RC and XML files, but it's not something I would like to do all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download and install the latest windows SDKs, they should include the latest versions of cl.exe, link.exe, midl.exe, etc.  You just need to point the executables path (tools->options->etc) at the new SDK dir and remove the build-in VS paths.